# undefined is not a function Error: $('#dialog').dialog({?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, typeerror

i am having error that says   `$("#dialog").dialog({`is undefined 
i did the same thing in a new MVC project and it works. but when i move the same code to another MVC project i am getting this error.
please help. I have added the jquery UI script. But still i get the same error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <body>
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
.......
 </form>
<div id="dialog" title="Create Album" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
        </body>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var InitialFacility = '@ViewBag.ID';
        $(document).ready(function () { 

            $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).tab('show');
            });

       $("#dialog").dialog({

                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'hi there',
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    //Load the CreateAlbumPartial action which will return 
                    // the partial view _CreateAlbumPartial
                    $(this).load('@Url.Action("GetRrfForm","FacilityAdd")');
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#modal-opener').click(function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            });
        });


    </script>
}
<div id="dialog" title="Create Album" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Comment: Its probably missing jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not including jQuery UI in your HTMLs.

You can download it from jQuery UI website and keep it inside your webapp and include it in the html as:

```
<script src="/<script_path_here>/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

OR

Use Google CDN links to include jQuery UI as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> in my _Layout? is it the same?

Comment: @user2803474, this path is ok only when you have scripts folder in root directory, otherwise use virtual path like- `@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

in the _Layout
i also had trouble loading jqxdatatable in the dialog window. but that was because i was using different verisons of jquery-ui.
So removed the second verion and used only jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js